# Multichannel recording from usb sound card using java

Tags: java, c++, c, audio, javasound

There is a java library that allows to simultaneously record N channels?
I have a USB M- Audio Fast Track Ultra R8 with 8 input channels.
I made a list of all devices using this code:

```
Mixer.Info [ ] = mixerInfo AudioSystem.getMixerInfo ();
System.out.println ( "Available mixers :");
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length ; cnt + + )
{
System.out.println ( mixerInfo [ cnt ] . GetName ());
}
```

obtaining this list:

```
Available mixers :
Audio Driver main
Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio )
Output ( 2 - M- Audio Fast Track Ultra 8R )
Primary driver of acquisition sounds
Microphone ( Realtek High Defini
Stereo Mix ( Realtek High Defini
Input ( 2 - M- Audio Fast Track Ul
Port Speakers ( Realtek High Defined
Port Stereo Mix ( Realtek High Defini
Port Microphone ( Realtek High Defini
Port Output ( 2 - M- Audio Fast Track U
Port Input ( 2 - M- Audio Fast Track Ul
```

I expect to see 8 input channels, but I see only one.
I can record from only one channel. 
How can I access all the channels?

Comment: Why the C and C++ tags?

Comment: Because C or C++ solutions are welcome.